# Driver support with AMD in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers

It's true that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is not supported with AMD Drivers, I have heard that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is not supported with AMD Drivers

Answer (score 2):

According to release notes, AMD drivers are **not** implemented yet. They will be in 16.04.1 version for sure, but it is possible they will be released sooner.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes